# Check for Birth Date

Tags: c#

In my sql database there is a column dateofbirth which contains the birthdate of my customers with this form: 31/12/2016 Column type is varchar(50).

I need to select the customers which 'day' and 'month' is like datetime.now
Here is my code:

```
   select name,mobile from memberform where dateofbirth like '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M") + "%'
```

The code works. But Today in 1-1-2017 i observed that it selects also customers where birthday is 1-10-xxxx.Why happen this?

Comment: Try _with DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M") + "/%'_

Comment: Said that, plan to change this column to a real datetime column as soon as possible

Comment: Why when column type is date it doesn work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard `%` will match any character even numbers, try updating your code to add another `/` after it like this:

```
'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M") + "/%'
```

Comment: Thank you it works but whywhen column type is date it doesn work?

Comment: Because datetimes in DBs are saved in a different format than what you use, this format is configurable in the DB setting.

Comment: Date format is example 2016-12-31. Right? how will change it for this?

Comment: Check this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for sql conversions.

Comment: I have already convert it. But how will i use select only date and day? where like datetime.now??

Comment: try `select to_char(dateofbirth, 'dd/mo') from memberform`

Comment: `to_char` is rdbms specific. It will not work for sql server, for example.

Comment: Then you need a more generic written C# class to support multiple DB providers, consider refactoring your code.